# Store SFSB reference in EJB 3.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I want to store a reference to a Stateful Session Bean and save it to the database or transfer it to another VM. As far as I read, in EJB 2.x this is possible using `getHandle()`. 
If I try to serialize the SFSB instance using Glassfish 3.1.1, I get the following exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate
```

Furthermore, I haven't found a way to obtain a SFSB handle. All references in the SFSB SessionContext to EFBHome, EFBObject, EFBLocalHome are null, even if the bean is properly being managed by the container. If I understand the spec correctly, there shouldn't be a need for handles in EJB 3.1 anyway, because developers should be able to use the SFSB reference directly.

[This article](http://www.jaceklaskowski.pl/wiki/Serializing_reference_of_@Stateful_session_beans_in_EJB_3.1_with_GlassFish_3.1) deals with the same issue, but the suggested use of the JavaEEObjectInputStream class did not expose the method readObject in my tests. I wonder how this approach could ever work.

Can anyone suggest a good approach to serialize a SFSB in Glassfish to store the reference? I don't want to attach the reference to a HTTPSession (I am just saying this, because people recommend this everywhere).

Comment: Maybe it is not a satisfying answer, but why not use the old raw EJB 2 code with jndi lookup and portable narrow object ? It still works even for EJB declared with 3.x annotations...

Answer (score 0):

this guy apparently found a glassfish specific solution:

http://www.jaceklaskowski.pl/wiki/Serializing_reference_of_@Stateful_session_beans_in_EJB_3.1_with_GlassFish_3.1

Comment: I already linked to this article in my question and also explained why it does not work for me.